# passing optional query string parameters to http service call

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

i need to make an API call which allows me to pass through optional query sting params

```
 retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string):Observable<IContracts> {  
  this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
      return http.get(this.basePath,{ 
      params: {  
       arg1:param1,
       arg2:param2,
      },
      withCredentials: false
    }) 
     .catch(this._errorHandler); 
  }
```

With the above code spinet, i have declared param2 as an optional parameter which can or cannot be passed through to the service call, however if param2 gets no value, it then returns `undefined` for which its understandable.

How do i make the service call to ignore the "arg2" parameter if no value was returned from the param2 variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string):Observable<IContracts> {  
    this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
    let params = {arg1: param1};
    if (param2)
        params = {arg1: param1, arg2: param2};

    return http.get(this.basePath, { 
        params: params,
        withCredentials: false
    }) 
    .catch(this._errorHandler); 
}
```

Hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

instead of passing two values in component, you could pass a object

//Assuming userService is your service
// **code in your component**

```
userService.retrieveConts({arg1:"val1",arg2:"val2"})
```

// **Code in userService**

```
retrieveConts(param:any):Observable<IContracts> {  
  this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
      return http.get(this.basePath,{ 
      params: param,
      withCredentials: false
    }) 
     .catch(this._errorHandler); 
  }
```

or you can also check for param2 and append it to object

```
retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string):Observable<IContracts> {  
    this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
    let params = {arg1: param1};
    if (param2) params.arg2 = param2;

        return http.get(this.basePath, { 
            params: params,
            withCredentials: false
        }) 
        .catch(this._errorHandler); 
    }
```

or pass empty val, if param2 is undefined or null

```
retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string):Observable<IContracts> {  
        this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 

            return http.get(this.basePath, { 
                params: {arg1: param1, arg2: param2 || ''},
                withCredentials: false
            }) 
            .catch(this._errorHandler); 
        }
```

or

```
  retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string=""):Observable<IContracts> {
           this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 

            return http.get(this.basePath, { 
                params: {arg1: param1, arg2: param2},
                withCredentials: false
            }) 
            .catch(this._errorHandler); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
retrieveConts(p1,p2?): Observable<IContracts> {
    this.basePath =  "/myConts";
    let params = {argument1: p1};
    if (p2)
        params = {argument1: p1, argument2: p2};

    return http.get(this.basePath, {
        params: params,
        withCredentials: false
    })
    .catch(this._errorHandler);
 }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

Switch to an object definition to shorten your code (other solutions will make it longer) :

```js
retrieveConts(params: { [key: string]: value: string }) {
  return http
    .get('/myConts', { 
      params,
      withCredentials: false
    }) 
    .catch(this._errorHandler); 
}
```

The argument is declared as an object that can has a string key with a string value, and you pass it directly as the params of your URL (properties with the same name don't need to be written twice)

Comment: But from this solution, Am passing more than 7 params, That time some of them are optional, but from this HTTPPARAMS, every time its passing complete params with undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one minor change:
Instead of:

```
    this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
    let params = {arg1: param1};
    if (param2) params.arg2 = param2;

        return http.get(this.basePath, { 
            params: params,
            withCredentials: false
        }) 
        .catch(this._errorHandler); 
    }
```

I would do:

```
        this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
    let params = {arg1: param1};
    if (param2) params['arg2'] = param2;

        return http.get(this.basePath, { 
            params: params,
            withCredentials: false
        }) 
        .catch(this._errorHandler); 
    }
```

By doing this you will avoid compilation error in Angular for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
retrieveConts(param1:string,param2?:string):Observable<IContracts> {  
     var params = {arg1:param1};

     if(param2){
         params = Object.assign(params,{arg2:param2})
     }

     this.basePath =  "/myConts"; 
         return http.get(this.basePath,{ 
         params: params,
         withCredentials: false
     }).catch(this._errorHandler); 
 }
```